# IF-Else Java Assignment

Tags: java

My assignment is to create several methods for the program. I seem to be stuck on these two the most.

Specifications are as follows: Need to use if n else statement 
name: setZipCode
arguments: 1 int
returns: boolean

what it does: stores its argument as the address' zip code.  If the
zip code is not a number between 90000 and 92000 (inclusive) (the
range of Los Angeles' zip codes) return false, otherwise return true.

name: getZipCode
arguments: none
returns: int
what it does: returns the value of the address' zip code

My code so far:

```
public int setZipCode(int zipCode){ //argument has to be type int zipCode and this method has to return a boolean
     if(zipCode >90000 && zipCode <92000){ //zipCode is between 90000 and 92000 
      return true; 
     }else{
      return false; 
     }
   public int getZipCode(){//no argument 
      return zipCode; //returns type int and return the value of the address zipcode
   }
}
```

When I run this code it gives error bad operand types for binary operator. 
Incompatible types: unexpected return value.

I declare int zipCode; early on and I don't understand how to get boolean and int working together.

If anyone can offer me help, as to what I am doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated and thank you.

I made the changes based on the advice each of you given me, it compiles now, but for some reason it still shows on command prompt that getZipCode and setZipCode failed! 
actual zip:0 
expected zip: 2

```
 public int getZipCode(){
      return zipCode; 
   }
   public boolean setZipCode(int zipCode) {
      if(zipCode >90000 && zipCode <92000){
         this.zipCode = zipCode;
         return true; 
      }
      else{
         return false; 
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: `public boolean setZipCode(int zipCode)`

Comment: For a function called `setZipCode` it doesn't actually, you know, *set* anything. Also, count your curly-braces `{}` and think about where `getZipCode` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote, `setZipCode` should return a boolean, and should probably set the zip code, as its name suggests :

```
public boolean setZipCode(int zipCode) {
     if(zipCode >90000 && zipCode <92000){
      this.zipCode = zipCode;
      return true; 
     }else{
      return false; 
     }
}
```

Besides that, you should move your `getZipCode()` method outside of the body of `setZipCode()` :

```
public int getZipCode() {
    return zipCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution

```
public class Address {
    private int zipCode;
    public boolean setZipCode(int zipCode){
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        return zipCode > 90000 && zipCode < 92000;
    }
}
```

Please note that, however, `setZipCode` has two jobs:

- setting the zip code
- checking the zip code

So probably you should split them. In addition, be careful using `boolean` error codes ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972307/when-to-return-bool-throw-an-exception-and-which-exception-to-throw))

Answer (score 0):

Your code has setZipCode declared as an int but you're returning booleans (true or false). Declale setZipCode as a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is on the sign of your method:

```
public int setZipCode(int zipCode){...}
```

You are saying that your method will return a int, but on code you are trying to return a boolean value (true/false).

To fix this problem you should update your method as:

```
public boolean setZipCode(int zipCode) { 
if(zipCode >90000 && zipCode <92000){ //zipCode is between 90000 and 92000 
     return true; 
 }else{
     return false; 
 }
}
```

Also I think that you missed a curly brace between the setZipCode method and getZipCode method.

Answer (score 0):

**setZipCode** method's return type should  be **boolean** as you're trying to return boolean value.Here is one line of code snippet that you should do:

```
public boolean setZipCode(int zipCode){
    return zipCode > 90000 && zipCode < 92000;
}
```